# Oracle if-else query to check table exist otherwise show a message?

Tags: database, oracle

When i am running below query first time its working but after again i am going to run this query i am getting exception

```
 Select count(*) into rec from all_tables where table_name='DefaultTable';
        if(rec=1) then
           CREATE TABLE  DefaultTable(
                  Code INT NOT NULL,
                  Code1 INT NOT NULL,
                  ResultCode INT NOT NULL,

                  CONSTRAINT DefaultTable_PK PRIMARY KEY(Code,Code1)
            );
            else
            PRMOPT DefaultTable Already Exist //To print in Console
             end if;
```

Can anyone tell what i am doing wrong? and what all i am doing wrong to write the above query ?

```
   Error starting at line 2 in command:
        if(rec=1) then
        Error report:
        Unknown Command

        Error starting at line 3 in command:
         CREATE TABLE  DefaultTable(
                          Code INT NOT NULL,
                          Code1 INT NOT NULL,
                          ResultCode INT NOT NULL,

                          CONSTRAINT DefaultTable_PK PRIMARY KEY(Code,Code1)
            Error at Command Line:3 Column:14
            Error report:
            SQL Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
            00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
            *Cause:    
            *Action:

            Error starting at line 16 in command:
            else
            Error report:
            Unknown Command

            Error starting at line 17 in command:
            PRMOPT Table Already Exist
            Error report:
            Unknown Command

            Error starting at line 18 in command:
            end if
            Error report:
            Unknown Command
```

Comment: Are you trying to do it in PL/SQL procedure?

Comment: @askkuber I belive the condition `(rec=1)` should be like `(rec=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as I understand the author is trying to do it in one sql query. But in Oracle you can not use IF statement in simple sql. Moreover, even if you use PL/SQL the DDL statements are not allowed to be directly invoked from PL/SQL code, so you should use dynamic SQL. I think, the following script will do what you want:

```
   DECLARE
     rec NUMBER;  
   BEGIN
      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO rec FROM all_tables WHERE table_name='DEFAULTTABLE';
      IF (rec=0) THEN   
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE  DefaultTable(
                  Code INT NOT NULL,
                  Code1 INT NOT NULL,
                  ResultCode INT NOT NULL,
                  CONSTRAINT DefaultTable_PK 
                       PRIMARY KEY(Code,Code1,ResultCode)
       )';
      ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('DefaultTable Already Exist');
      END IF;
    END;
```

Please, note that in order to see the messages printed via dbms_output, you should execute:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
```

Comment: Still your script also giving exception and printining everything wile i want simple message Table already exist Like print statement

Comment: Which exception do you get? I have checked it before posting and it works without errors for sure.

Comment: I think I got what you say. You want to get just a text message, not an exception. I have edited the answer correspondently.

Comment: No need to run it many times, it should work from the first execution. There is only two ways for you to see the message: an exception raised or the text printed (which can only be done through dbms_output). If both of cases does not satisfy you, there is nothing I can do.

Comment: When first i am ruuning SET SERVEROUTPUT ON; then i am able to see message but if i am not running SET SERVEROUTPUT ON; first time no message is shown

Comment: I have noted in the answer that to see the message you should run this SET statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error message you will notice it says:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

This means you are trying to create a table that already exists. That explains why it runs the first time and not any more after that.

Check the entries in all_tables and you will find that Oracle creates tablenames in uppercase. So check for 'DEFAULTTABLE'.

Comment: Thasy why i added if else statement id table exist print message table already exist why it is going to create table again?

Comment: Because you have to look for the tablename in uppercase.